# Facebook Open Graph not picking up images (or anything in debugger)

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

this is really doing my head in. I have a site that is not allowing facebook to scrape data and show og:image parameters.

I have tried the following:

- remove any disallows in robots text (just in case)
- Make images smaller (they were huge)
- check and double check markup of og tags
- tried also adding the images to the page  in case they also needed to be
  there rather than displayed in a js slider
- Checked blacklist of URL
- cleared browsing history (as described by another user in my searches)
- uploaded a resized thumbnail rather than using php to create the dynamic thumb (images are dynamic on this site)
- created a blank test static html page with pretty much nothing on it to really
  trouble shoot the issue.

it still doesn't work.

Here is my test page code. i removed urls for now. but if you want to check the page just ask me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.co/test/" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="my site Test Page" />
    <meta property='og:site_name' content='my site' />

    <title>Homepage</title>

    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>

    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.co/test/43FINFAdeleThiel1.jpg" />
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://www.mysite.co/test/43FINFAdeleThiel1.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance everyone, this is really eating up my time :(

Comment: Have you tried https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ If so, what does it show?